# TFS - Fixing a historic changeset

Tags: tfs, branch, changeset

TFS question. 
I have an issue where our organisation (before my time) released binaries to clients based on a single main branch. There was no labelling, as such, but there are changesets. 
Over time - different customers are on different versions. When I get an issue I need to resolve in an old version - I don't always have the luxury of deploying the fix from within the Main branch as there could be dependencies in there that will fail in the older release. I can get the most likely match of the clients codebase from a changeset. Now my question is this - what is the standard way to approach this? Do I simply GET the relevant changeset, modify the relevant file(s), commit to a new branch, schedule a build - specifying the temporary branch - and deploy from that? Or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance. - Nialler

Comment: You can branch from a specific changeset number, get latest on that branch and fix the issue.

Comment: Get the most likely match... I think I'm having a panic attack.

Comment: I'm always having panic attacks here, Tony. :-(

Comment: So branch from  changeset - get latest, fix issue, then what? Can I check in changes to that changeset and schedule a TFS build against that changeset?